# shutting off navbar javascript except on specific pages in ruby

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following javascript function as part of a theme I am using for a webpage that also uses Bootstrap.  The function alternates two bootstrap CSS classes for the navbar based on whether a user has scrolled away from the top of the page.

I only want this function to work when a user is on the initial welcome page of my website, where the 'navbar-default' class is appropriate.  On all other pages, I want the navbar to remain 'navbar-inverse'

Can anyone tell me how to do this in the javascript file?  I am using Ruby.

```
// Toggle navbar on scroll
$window.scroll(function() {

    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > 0 && $('.navbar-default').length) {
        navbar.removeClass('navbar-default').addClass('navbar-inverse');
    } else if (scrollTop == 0) {
        navbar.removeClass('navbar-inverse').addClass('navbar-default');
    }

});
```

Comment: Depends on your setup. Is the JS part of a compiled JS that's the same for all rendered pages or does each page get different JS? Are you using a framework like Angular or React, rendering one application page with JS page-navigation?

Comment: Yes it is a single js file for all rendered pages

Comment: There is a single ruby file application. HTML.erb that calls all of the style sheets and js but there are different pages.  The HTML 'head' is the same for all pages but 'yield' is separate for each page.

Comment: One way might be to render an identifying variable only in the welcome page. `<%= <script>let isWelcomePage = true</script> %>` and in the common JS file wrap anything you want included in an `if (!isWelcomePage){ ...`

Comment: But that's kind of awkward and confusing. I suppose a clearer, more scalable way might be to reserve the common JS file for truly common scripts, and separate out code that's specific to certain HTML into other JS files. Then import the appropriate JS files as needed. (I think the JS files can be imported from the 'public' folder in the body of the relevant HTML page.)